# Rules of Algebra in Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

For each of the following rules, either prove that it is true in every group G, or give a counterexample to
show that it is false in some groups.

(1) If $x^2$ = $e$, then $x = e$.

(2) If $x^2$ = $x$, then $x = e$

Can someone help me. I honestly don't know where to start and I want to understand. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your hint in the second statement is that you can right multiply both sides  of $x^2 = x$ by a certain group element to get $x = e$. Do you see what this element is? Look at the group axioms again.

Comment: is it the identity element?

Comment: You can look at the answer below. Try and write down a full proof of $(2)$ , it can only be helpful to you.

Comment: One more hint for (2): you want $e$ in the right hand side where there is $x$. How do you get $e$ from $x$? What is the natural choice for an element $y$ such that $xy=e$?

Comment: a) False if G={e,x} the group is 
$e x
x e$
if we have $x^-1 = e$ 
then $x*x^-1=x*e$ 
so $e=x*e$ 

b) True 
$x^2=x 
x*x=x
x*x*x^-1=x*x^-1 
x*e=e$

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints/solutions:

(1) Consider $\mathbb{Z}_2$

(2) Try using $x^{-1}$

Comment: a) False if G={e,x} the group is 
$e x
x e$
if we have $x^-1 = e$ 
then $x*x^-1=x*e$ 
so $e=x*e$ 

b) True 
$x^2=x 
x*x=x
x*x*x^-1=x*x^-1 
x*e=e$